# Postfix email sent only after approval process

Tags: email, configuration, smtp, email-validation, postfix-mta

I have a question about configuration of mail server. I need a mail server that can send the emails only if some one will approve the message. To explain better I make an example:

- The sender write the message using a simple email manager;
- The email isn't send directly to the recipient but is send to a specific email address (for example email-controller@mydomain.ext);
- the controller could approve the email or reject;
- reject is simple he can put the email into the trash;
- to approve he should forward to the email that the previous sender wanted;
- the best solution should be if the recipient see only the previous sender

I understand that is not easy to explain and is a complex project, but i hope someone can send me some suggestion.